# Joining two SELECT statements using Outer Join with multiple alias

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I have a complicated select statement that when it is executed, I give it a date or date range I want and the output comes out.  The problem is I don't know how to join the same SQL statement with the first Statement having 1 date range and the second statement having another data range.  Example below:

When I execute the select statement, I choose for the Month of November:
EMPLID     NAME     Current_Gross_Hours(November)

When I execute the select statement again, I choose from January to November:
EMPLID    NAME     Year_To_Date_Hours(January - November)

What I want:
EMPLID    NAME     Current_Gross_Hours(November)  Year_To_Date_Hours(January - November)

The SQL Select statement runs correctly if execute by themselves. But I don't know how to join them.
Here is the SQL code that I want to write, but I don't know how to write the SQL statement correctly.  Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
SUM("PSA"."AL_HOURS") AS "Current Gross Hours", "PSJ"."EMPLID","PSP"."NAME"
FROM
"PS_JOB" "PSJ", "PS_EMPLOYMENT" "PSE", "PS_PERSONAL_DATA" "PSP", "PS_AL_CHK_HRS_ERN" "PSA"
WHERE
((("PSA"."CHECK_DT" = TO_DATE('2011-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
("PSJ"."PAYGROUP" = 'SK2') AND
(("PSJ"."EFFSEQ"= ( 
    SELECT MAX("INNERALIAS"."EFFSEQ")
    FROM "PS_JOB" INNERALIAS 
    WHERE "INNERALIAS"."EMPL_RCD_NBR" = "PSJ"."EMPL_RCD_NBR"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EMPLID" = "PSJ"."EMPLID"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EFFDT" = "PSJ"."EFFDT")
AND
"PSJ"."EFFDT" = ( 
    SELECT MAX("INNERALIAS"."EFFDT")
    FROM "PS_JOB" INNERALIAS 
    WHERE "INNERALIAS"."EMPL_RCD_NBR" = "PSJ"."EMPL_RCD_NBR"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EMPLID" = "PSJ"."EMPLID"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EFFDT" <= SYSDATE))))) 
AND
("PSJ"."EMPLID" = "PSE"."EMPLID" ) AND ("PSJ"."EMPLID" = "PSP"."EMPLID" ) AND ("PSJ"."FILE_NBR" = "PSA"."FILE_NBR" ) AND ("PSJ"."PAYGROUP" = "PSA"."PAYGROUP" ) AND ("PSE"."EMPLID" = "PSP"."EMPLID" )
GROUP BY
"PSJ"."EMPLID", "PSP"."NAME"
) AS "Q1"

LEFT JOIN


(SELECT DISTINCT
SUM("PSA"."AL_HOURS") AS "YEAR_TO_DATE Gross Hours", "PSJ"."EMPLID"
FROM
"PS_JOB" "PSJ", "PS_EMPLOYMENT" "PSE", "PS_PERSONAL_DATA" "PSP", "PS_AL_CHK_HRS_ERN" "PSA"
WHERE
((("PSA"."CHECK_DT" BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2011-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))  AND
("PSJ"."PAYGROUP" = 'SK2') AND
(("PSJ"."EFFSEQ"= ( 
    SELECT MAX("INNERALIAS"."EFFSEQ")
    FROM "PS_JOB" INNERALIAS 
    WHERE "INNERALIAS"."EMPL_RCD_NBR" = "PSJ"."EMPL_RCD_NBR"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EMPLID" = "PSJ"."EMPLID"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EFFDT" = "PSJ"."EFFDT")
AND
"PSJ"."EFFDT" = ( 
    SELECT MAX("INNERALIAS"."EFFDT")
    FROM "PS_JOB" INNERALIAS 
    WHERE "INNERALIAS"."EMPL_RCD_NBR" = "PSJ"."EMPL_RCD_NBR"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EMPLID" = "PSJ"."EMPLID"
    AND "INNERALIAS"."EFFDT" <= SYSDATE))))) 
AND
("PSJ"."EMPLID" = "PSE"."EMPLID" ) AND ("PSJ"."EMPLID" = "PSP"."EMPLID" ) AND ("PSJ"."FILE_NBR" = "PSA"."FILE_NBR" ) AND ("PSJ"."PAYGROUP" = "PSA"."PAYGROUP" ) AND ("PSE"."EMPLID" = "PSP"."EMPLID" )
GROUP BY
"PSJ"."EMPLID"
) AS "Q2"
 ON "Q1"."EMPLID"="Q2"."EMPLID"
ORDER BY
"Q1"."NAME"
```

Comment: Which SQL are you using... MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle???

Comment: I'm not sure I can do VIEW.  I think I'm just given query access only.  I will try VIEW and see what happens.  SQL is ORACLE

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a `SELECT ... FROM` at the start.  The `AS` keyword only works when creating column aliases, not query block aliases.  Quotation marks are only necessary for case-sensitive column names - they don't look incorrect in your example but they frequently cause mistakes.

```
SELECT Q1.NAME, ...
FROM
(
     SELECT ...
) Q1
JOIN
(
     SELECT ...
) Q2
ON Q1.EMPLID=Q2.EMPLID
ORDER BY Q1.NAME
```

Comment: So instead of using my table alias of "PSP" with the field "NAME" ("PSP"."NAME"), I should us the select statement alias of "Q1" instead and leave the rest as is?  Thanks.